# AS3 Array sorton() issue

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to sort an array of "tile" objects in as3 by the value of its "realY" property.
This is my code:

```
    tiles.sortOn("realY", Array.DESCENDING);
    tiles.reverse();

    for each(var t:Tile in tiles)
    {
            trace(t.nearness);
    }
```

This is the output:

```
    6
6
6
6
6
7
7
7
7
7
7
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
11
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
12
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
13
14
14
14
14
14
14
14
14
14
14
14
14
14
15
15
15
15
15
15
15
15
15
15
15
15
15
15
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
16
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
17
18
18
18
18
18
18
18
18
18
18
18
18
18
18
18
18
18
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
19
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
20
21
21
21
21
21
21
21
21
21
21
21
21
21
21
21
21
21
21
21
21
22
22
22
22
22
22
22
22
22
22
22
22
22
22
22
22
22
22
22
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
23
24
24
24
24
24
24
24
24
24
24
24
24
24
24
24
24
24
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
25
26
26
26
26
26
26
26
26
26
26
26
26
26
26
26
27
27
27
27
27
27
27
27
27
27
27
27
27
27
28
28
28
28
28
28
28
28
28
28
28
28
28
29
29
29
29
29
29
29
29
29
29
29
29
30
30
30
30
30
30
30
30
30
30
30
2
31
31
31
31
31
31
31
31
31
31
32
32
32
32
32
32
32
32
32
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
34
34
34
34
34
34
34
35
35
35
35
35
35
36
36
36
36
36
37
37
37
37
38
38
38
39
39
40
3
3
4
4
4
5
5
5
5
```

As you can see, there are some random small numbers at the end. Why is this happening?
Thanks

Comment: Figured it out,
the sortOn sorts by string by default, so I changed the sortOn to this:

    tiles.sortOn("realY", Array.NUMERIC);

ascending is also default, so I didn't have to sort descending and then flip

Answer (score 6):

Try using your `sortOn` like this:

```
tiles.sortOn("realY", Array.NUMERIC | Array.DESCENDING);
```

By default Flash is sorting in alphabetical order. Check the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sortOn%28%29) for more info.

Besides that, you're tracing the `nearness` property, not the `realY` property you sorted. So maybe that's a problem too.